# What is ${variable//,/ } in bash?

Tags: bash

A script is capturing a serie of comma delimited arguments and I'm wondering how it works. Why are there 3 slashes after cryptoptions inside a subshell call :

```
for cryptopt in ${cryptoptions//,/ }; do
```

What is this syntax corresponding to ?

Comment: ...btw, this (`for foo in $bar`, whether or not `$bar` has commas mutated to spaces as given here) is bad practice, and very prone to bugs. Don't use it in your own code.

Comment: ...look at what happens if you try to pass, say, the pair of arguments `-name '*.txt'` this way, especially if you have any text files in your current directory. Or look at what happens if you try to pass a single argument containing whitespace.

Comment: The right way to handle a comma-separated list would be something more like: `IFS=, read -r -a opts <<<"$cryptoptions"`, which makes an *array* called `opts`; that array can then be iterated over with `for x in "${opts[@]}"`, printed one-to-a-line with `printf '%s\n' "${opts[@]}"`, have all its options amended to a command line with `./somecommand "${opts[@]}"`, etc.

Comment: ...related to the above objections: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: ...back to your immediate question, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe for a long list of available parameter expansions and what they mean/do.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a "sed like variable call in bash",
it has nothing to with sed at all.

From `man bash`, in the **Pattern substitution** section:

> ```
>    ${parameter/pattern/string}
>           Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pat-
>           tern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is  expanded  and
>           the  longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with
>           string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are
>           replaced   with  string.   Normally  only  the  first  match  is
>           replaced.
> ```

In other words:

- `${cryptoptions/,/ }` : replace the first `,` with a space
- `${cryptoptions//,/ }` : replace every `,` with a space

And the `for cryptopt in words; do ...; done` you have around this is a loop.
For each word in `words`, it will execute the loop body, the code between `do` and `done`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cryptoptions=foo,bar,baz
for cryptopt in ${cryptoptions//,/ }; do
    echo $cryptopt
done
```

It effectively corresponds to:

```
for cryptopt in $(echo "$cryptoptions" | sed 's/,/ /g'); do
    echo $cryptopt
done
```

and utilizes the fact that unquoted variables split on whitespace.

The former is is much faster, because it doesn't spawn processes.

Comment: It might be worth showing an actual best-practices alternative -- ie. something that allows options to contain whitespace, glob characters, etc.